# Android development VS Spring MVC & Hibernate & Maven learning curve

Tags: android, spring, hibernate, maven

I have a problem: I am on my final year project and I can develop an Android application or a Web server (which imports/exports data from/to an XML file, with user authentication and so).

Web server must use Spring MVC, Hibernate and Maven but I haven't ever done anything with those technologies. Same problem with Android development. My skills are Java (just Java, not Java EE), C, HTML and relational DB. That is what we learn in spanish university.

What about both choices learning curve? Which one is less pronounced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My skills are Java (just Java, not Java EE), C, HTML and relational DB

**If the time available for this project is short:**

As you don't know Java EE, I suggest to go with Android development.

**Else :**

I suggest to go with a web server app, because it will be a good learning curve as you will learn Java EE, Spring and Hibernate. And also it will come in handy in the future if you plan your career as a Java developer .

Comment: Thanks for your reply @invariant
I thought that: learning JEE, Maven, Spring and Hibernate will be very useful for working after my FYP... but I am so lost on all those technologies... I am reading "Spring in action" (Manning).

Comment: Ok, I will look for tutorials about Servlets then. Thanks for your help @invariant

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, depends on the type of Android application you need to develop. If you need a complex, beautiful and polished UI, than I think the 2 learning curves are similar. If you need an application that just does its job, Android is easier to learn than Spring + hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @alex. The Android application can't be a simple application since it is my final year proyect so I suppose that learning curve will be as pronnounced as in the Maven + Spring + Hibernate project regarding your answer.